# How can I resize a table to a page (\textwidth) but also that takes multiples pages if needed?

Tags: tables, longtable, width, resize

My problem is that I have resized the scale for keeping the text on the text width, but then it overlaps the page number: [image]

My code:

```
\begin{table}[H]

  \centering

    \caption{Table}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{ 
    \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
    \hline
    1 & -20 & 0 & 40 & 25 & 25 & 25 & 25 & 13943 & -4,44 & -0,81 \\
    \hline
    2 & -20 & 0 & 40 & 75 & 50 & 25 & 25 & 13968 & -6,4745 & 0,6761  \\
    \hline
    3 & -20 & 0 & 40 & 75 & 50 & 75 & 50 & 1395 & -5,23 & -0,285  \\
    \hline
    ...
    \end{tabular}
    }
\end{table}%
```

Comment: For a multi-page table, use `longtable` or `longtabu`, you can't use `\resizebox` with these, but you can choose a smaller font size.

Answer (score 1):

Please proceed with below `longtable` environment (works with package `longtable` i.e., `\usepackage{longtable}`) instead of `table`:

```
\begin{longtable}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \caption{}\\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
    \hline
    1 & -20 & 0 & 40 & 25 & 25 & 25 & 25 & 13943 & -4,44 & -0,81 \\
    \hline
    2 & -20 & 0 & 40 & 75 & 50 & 25 & 25 & 13968 & -6,4745 & 0,6761  \\
    \hline
    3 & -20 & 0 & 40 & 75 & 50 & 75 & 50 & 1395 & -5,23 & -0,285  \\
    \hline
    ................
    \end{longtable}
```

[image]

Comment: Also, as pointed out in the comments to the original question, you can use `longtabu` (and `booktabs`) for better and nicer results.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package exactly for this purpose: `ltxtable`
It merges `tabularx` (which you should definetly use anyway, don't resize the table with `\resizebox`) and `longtable`.

With `tabularx` you can define the width of the table (in your case `\textwidth`) and longtable (as pointed out in the upper answer) provides page-breaking mechanisms. You need to write the table to a file, but with big tables that's anyway a good idea.

`tabularx` introduces a new column type: `X`. This stretches accordingly to the final width, so if you have two columns of this type and the width of the table is the textwidth, each column will be exactly half as wide. I fill use this mechanism but introduce new column types for center and left alignement.
There are two of each kind, since it is sometimes necessary to resize them. This is done with the `\hsize` command. See column types `E` and `F` and my example. I had to play a bit with the widths, this is not quite straightforward. Note that the total width must be the number of the columns, so if you use the width modifier `0.75` in one column, you must make up for the missing `0.25` in the remaining columns.

That said, let's look at the code:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}

% my settings, i use lualatex, but you can also use pdflatex without problems
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
% also for lualatex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

% packages (ltxtable loads both tabularx and longtable)
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{booktabs} % see text below

% define new columns
\newcolumntype{E}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{F}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

% first table
\begin{filecontents}{table.tex}
    \begin{longtable}{|F{0.3}|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|E{1.2}|E{1.3}|E{1.2}|}
        \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
        \hline
        1 & -20 & 0 & 40 & 25 & 25 & 25 & 25 & 13943 & -4,44 & -0,81 \\
        \hline
        2 & -20 & 0 & 40 & 75 & 50 & 25 & 25 & 13968 & -6,4745 & 0,6761  \\
        \hline
        3 & -20 & 0 & 40 & 75 & 50 & 75 & 50 & 1395 & -5,23 & -0,285  \\
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{filecontents}

% second (almost the same) table
\begin{filecontents}{table2.tex}
    \begin{longtable}{F{0.3}CCCCCCCE{1.2}E{1.3}E{1.2}}
        \toprule
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
        \midrule
        1 & -20 & 0 & 40 & 25 & 25 & 25 & 25 & 13943 & -4,44 & -0,81 \\
        \midrule
        2 & -20 & 0 & 40 & 75 & 50 & 25 & 25 & 13968 & -6,4745 & 0,6761  \\
        \midrule
        3 & -20 & 0 & 40 & 75 & 50 & 75 & 50 & 1395 & -5,23 & -0,285  \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    % typeset both tables
    \LTXtable{\textwidth}{table.tex}
    \LTXtable{\textwidth}{table2.tex}
\end{document}
```

The `E` and `C` and the `F` and `L` columns do the same (center and left alignement), but for `E` and `F` you can give a relative width, which was needed for the wider columns.

As you can see, i've put two tables in the document. The first corresponds with your layout. The second one is a suggestion, as vertical bars are often disencouraged. Take a look in a paper/book/some document. Most of the times, the tables are typeset as in my second example, without vertical bars, one big headline, smaller middle lines and a big bottom line. This is exactly what `booktabs` does, hence the name.

A last suggestion: think about splitting up your data in some way, maybe one column is not important or something. *Really* think about this, i have the feeling a table longer than one page with so many columns will be totally unreadable. Better to use more and smaller tables.
[image: First table]
[image: Second table]